# Converted VmWare Image does not boot in Virtual Box

Tags: vmware, virtualbox

I have a .vddx virtual image which boots in VmWare, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with Sun Virtual Box. In Sun Virtual Box, I created a new Virtual Machine and pointed it at the vddx file from VmWare. When I try to boot the virtual machine, Sun Virtual Box says that the volume is not bootable. VmWare is able to boot from this virtual machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what might be causing the problem? Is there a conversion utility that I need to run? Any debugging options that I could turn on?

Answer (score 1):

.vddx? I have never heard of it. Even googled it in vain. Create a custom VM in virtualbox, use the .vmdk file that VMware used

Answer (score 1):

The solution RainDoctor gave works with some but not all OS, for instance Windows 2008 will give a blue screen when booting. I used [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/moving_a_vmware_vm_to) tutorial to get it work.